# Answering in comments

Tags: discussion, answers

When someone posts a really simple question which can be answer in just one line, what would be the best thing to do?

1. Answer in comments and leave, which means there might not be any appreciation at all.
2. Answer in the answer box with a bit more information on their question and get appreciation with upvotes and may be 15 more points if your answer is accepted.

Comment: Put it this way: if you post the answer as a comment, it's very likely someone else will copy-paste that to an answer and get the rep.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. Next time, I will play well :)

Comment: I think you are confusing "appreciation" with "reward." I leave comments all the time, and I suspect that they are often appreciated (particularly when they are there to point the user toward an answer or helpful contextual information), even though I am not rewarded for them in any way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put it this way: if you post the answer as a comment, it's very likely someone else will copy-paste that to an answer and get the rep.

Comment: My point, therefore, stands :D

Comment: @tombull89 You proved it man :)

Comment: @tombull89 And this is now one my most voted answer on all the StackExchange websites, you really made your point :-)

Comment: +1 because this was both clever and unscrupulous

Answer (score 5):

Always go for the second option. There is a clear-cut distinction between a comment and an answer.

A **comment** is meant to ask for relevant information or clarification. An **answer** answers the question - straightforward, isn't it?

So, never give an answer in the comments section of a post. Having said this, if the simplicity of the question disqualifies it as an SO question, you're better off flagging it as e.g. broad or off-topic.

Comment: Seems like you are going the smart way :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure about your answer you **should** post it as an answer, use comments to : request clarification,  leave constructive criticism...

As explained well here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment